# Cisco Jabber in a VMware virtual machine: the interlocutor hears me, but I cannot hear the interlocutor

Tags: windows-10, audio, vmware-workstation, cisco-jabber

I use Cisco Jabber 11.8.4 Build 52954 in a virtual machine.

- Guest: Windows 10 x64 1607 Professional
- Host: Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate
- VMware Workstation Pro 14.1.1 build-7528167

When I make a call on Jabber, the interlocutor hears me, but I cannot hear the interlocutor. What could the issue be?

---

I checked:

- The sound output in the virtual machine works (except with Jabber), e.g. I can listen to YouTube videos in Google Chrome. Even the sound test in Jabber works fine.
- I tried with many different interlocutors: I'm sure the issue comes from my side.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use Cisco Virtualization Experience Media Edition (a.k.a. Cisco VXME).

- Description: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collaboration-endpoints/virtualization-experience-media-engine/index.html
- Download link: https://software.cisco.com/download/navigator.html?mdfid=284585947&i=rm

From a Cisco employee on https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/jabber-clients/jabber-on-windows-no-sound-when-using-my-pc-for-phone-calls/m-p/2786914/highlight/true#M15684:

> Jabber needs especial plugin (comes iwith Cisco VXME) (called "Virtual Channel") to propage audio from guest to host machine

I haven't tried it yet as Cisco VXME cannot be freely downloaded.